# SQL alwayson AG Disaster Recovery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups, windows-server, disaster-recovery

Need advise on below:

I have 2 node alwayson AG on Primary Sync mode in the current configuration and fsw is in Primary DC only
Actually during Switchover the entire DC 2 node and fsw will be down
Which DR configuration should I opt in this situation for little manual steps and DR can come up without much issues:
2 Node Async in DR
1 Node Async in DR

I am using SQL 2012 Enterprise, Windows2012 OS

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DR solutions are not built around existing infrastructure, they are built around business requirements. Define your business need for DR and build a system that supports that need.

P.S. You need to build a new system anyway.  SQL 2012 is out of mainstream support and has less then 24 months before end of extended support (July 12, 2022).